# Criar nova tabela a partir de outra no sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou fazendo esta **query**:

```
CREATE TABLE nova_tabela AS
SELECT * FROM tabela_copiada;
```

Estou recebendo o seguinte **erro**:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'

Já pesquisei a sintaxe me parece correta. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: tabela temporária ou física ?

Comment: @LeonardoSilva A construção `CREATE TABLE ... AS (SELECT ... FROM ...)` funciona em alguns gerenciadores de banco de dados mas não no SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

A syntax correta é

```
SELECT colunas 
INTO tabelaNova 
FROM TabelaQueDesejaCopiar 
WHERE Condicao
```

> SELECT…INTO cria uma tabela nova no grupo de arquivos padrão e insere
>   nela as linhas resultantes da consulta

[Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql)

Seu select ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * INTO nova_tabela FROM tabela_copiada
```

Comment: Complementando, quando se quer criar a nova tabela com a mesma estrutura mas sem dados, basta utilizar restrição que retorne falso; por exemplo: `WHERE 1 = 0`